# Not understanding why this component not showing images

Tags: next.js

I am still learning React and working on Next JS banner for work. I can't figure out why is this addBanner component not showing on the server and not showing any text too. What do you think I should do? Thank you!

Link to the issue on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-clarke-z5855?file=/pages/addBanner.js

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had forgotten to give Capital letter to the first letter of my component and give width and height to Image.:)